# I want to append my api response to datatable

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, datatable, fetch

I have a response in json which I am getting from the api. I want to embed that into the datatable. One by one so they can be shown in a row. But i am getting an error and the all of the data in being appended under one column.

This is my json response

[image]

And I am trying to read the data through the fetch API and then appending it to the table.

```
<table id="table1" class="display" style="min-width: 845px">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>File Name</th>
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                     </thead>
                                    <tbody id="tbodydata"> 
                            
                                </tbody>
                                </table>
```

fetch api call is below

```
fetch('https://e728-185-202-239-227.ngrok.io/pakgentext/getFilesByPath/?path='+product , {

                method: "GET",
               
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((resp) => {
                console.log(resp);
                if(resp.message == "Success"){

                  
                    $.each(resp.doc, function (index, value) { 
                        $("#table1  ").append('<td>'+value+'</td>');
                    });
        
                }else{

                }
            })
```

I tried looping through my response to append it one by one but its all appending in the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take action on `resp.doc.txtFiles`, not `resp.doc`. Look through the array and construct a table row from each item. For better performance it is better to first generate the HTML of all rows, then update the DOM, e.g. reduce the number of `.append()` to one.

From your example it is not clear what the table columns ID, File Name, and Action entail, so I took a guess.

Here is the code to generate the HTML from the response, and update the DOM:

```
                if(resp.message == "Success") {
                    let html = resp.doc.txtFiles.map(fileName => {
                        let id = fileName.replace(/\.txt$/, '');
                        let action = '??';
                        return '<tr> <td>'+id+'</td> <td>'+fileName+'</td> <td>'+action+'</td> </tr>';
                    }).join(' ');
                    $("#table1 tbody").append(html);
                }
```

**UPDATE 1** The OP changed the format of the JSON response to:

```
{
  "message": "Success",
  "doc": [
    { "filename": "PhD-D-E_T-F-001.txt" },
    { "filename": "PhD-D-E_T-F-002.txt" },
    { "filename": "PhD-D-E_T-F-003.txt" }
  ]
}
```

With this, the code changes to this:

```
                if(resp.message == "Success") {
                    let html = resp.doc.map(obj => {
                        let fileName = obj.filename;
                        let id = fileName.replace(/\.txt$/, '');
                        let action = '??';
                        return '<tr> <td>'+id+'</td> <td>'+fileName+'</td> <td>'+action+'</td> </tr>';
                    }).join(' ');
                    $("#table1 tbody").append(html);
                }
```

Comment: u did a good guess sir. But i am not getting ID in my response so I have to generate it by myself. I am only getting the name of the text files which I have to append into my table. And Action is where I want to perform download action on my file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? If so would you care to accept it (see gray checkmark)?

Comment: it didnt worked
iguess my json response is not in proper format?

Comment: Is your JSON response as stated in your question? I tested my answer with that response. Do a `console.log()` to check

Comment: yes yes its same. I tried changing my json data let me update my question.
But still  i didnt got the response properly embedded into the table

Comment: See **UPDATE 1**. Next time please state the proper JSON response from start

Comment: Instead of count inside ID , you showed some textfiles names, what is that about

Comment: I don't understand your question. If it is about `let id = fileName.replace(/\.txt$/, '')`, it creates the ID from filename, such as `PhD-D-E_T-F-001` from `PhD-D-E_T-F-001.txt`. You might want to generate some other ID.